# RotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true) and .setFillEnabled(true) does not work

Tags: android, image, animation, imageview, rotateanimation

I'm trying to rotate 3 `imageViews` with a `rotateAnimation`.  I calculate the degrees to rotate every 30ms.  If the angle changed, I create the rotateAnimation:

```
rpmAnim=new RotateAnimation((float)Rpmcurrentdegree, (float)Rpmdegree, ivNadel.getWidth()/2, ivNadel.getHeight()/2);
rpmAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
rpmAnim.setFillAfter(true);
```

...and then I start the animation of the imageView:

```
 ivNadel.startAnimation(rpmAnim);
```

The rotation works fine, but when the degrees **do not** change, it jumps back to its starting position.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the setAnimationListener on rpmAnim:

```
rpmAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

          // here rotate the image

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    });
```

to rotate the image you **can**

1. extends ImageView in order to create your custom image view
2. override onDraw
3. set your rotation angle
4. invalidate your custom image view

the overridden `onDraw`  could look like:

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.save()
     canvas.rotate(your rotation angle...)
     super.onDraw(canvas)
     canvas.restore()
 }
```